# Adding an image to a PDF file in Swift

Tags: swift, image, pdf

Hi i'm currently trying to get a image in a imageview added to my PDF file.

i already have text added to the PDF im just looking to get an image added in too.

Heres what i got so far

```
@IBAction func CreatePDF(sender: AnyObject) {
    // 1. Create a print formatter

    let html = "<b>Hello <i>World!</i></b>"
    let fmt = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: html)

    // 2. Assign print formatter to UIPrintPageRenderer

    let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
    render.addPrintFormatter(fmt, startingAtPageAtIndex: 0)

    // 3. Assign paperRect and printableRect

    let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8) // A4, 72 dpi
    let printable = CGRectInset(page, 0, 0)

    render.setValue(NSValue(CGRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
    render.setValue(NSValue(CGRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

    // 4. Create PDF context and draw

    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectZero, nil)

    for i in 1...render.numberOfPages() {

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
        render.drawPageAtIndex(i - 1, inRect: bounds)
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // 5. Save PDF file

    let path = "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())file.pdf"
    pdfData.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
    print("open \(path)") // command to open the generated file
}
```

Comment: try properly creating your path

Comment: its only temp until i can add images to the pdf file

Comment: Looks to me it is missing a "/" between the directory and your file. BTW What is your question? What is not working?

Comment: Thats not my problem at the moment the whole code only adds text i want to add images to the pdf and i don't know how to implement this into this code i have

Comment: What do you need to do ? Just create a layout with images and text and save them to a pdf file ? Create a UIView and draw your elements into it and save your view layer as pdf

Comment: i have its just the image part im failing to get to grips with to add it along side the text i add to the pdf